# Having trouble understanding a crash report with no related methods from my code

Tags: ios, crash-reports, afnetworking-2, cfnetwork

Looks like it's related to the network thread, most other threads are in a "mach_msg_trap" state. The 4th thread on the list is the one that crashed. I'm using AFNetworking on iOS 7.1

I appreciate any idea or thought that might help me investigate this issue.

```
Threads
_________________________________
Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924da84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91e559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91ccbf __CFRunLoopRun + 863
3     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5     GraphicsServices                      0x335c12eb GSEventRunModal + 139
6     UIKit                                 0x3113c845 UIApplicationMain + 1137
7     Vieu                                  0x000f4f87 main (main.m:17)
8     libdyld.dylib                         0x391a9ab7 start + 3

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924d838 kevent64 + 24
1     libdispatch.dylib                     0x39196623 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 39

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924da84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91e559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91cc79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4     CoreFoundation                        0x2e8cb0db CFRunLoopRun + 99
5     CoreMotion                            0x2ef3f369 CLSF_thorntonUpdate_6x6 + 57225
6     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     libdispatch.dylib                     0x39199758 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 120
1     libsystem_network.dylib               0x3929c2df tcp_connection_cancel + 107
2     CFNetwork                             0x2e54d3d9 _ZN12SocketStreamD2Ev + 89
3     CFNetwork                             0x2e54d371 _ZN12SocketStreamD1Ev + 21
4     CoreFoundation                        0x2e883e2f CFRelease + 467
5     CFNetwork                             0x2e54cd69 _ZN27CoreReadStreamWithCallBacksD2Ev + 45
6     CoreFoundation                        0x2e883e2f CFRelease + 467
7     CFNetwork                             0x2e56b437 _ZN14HTTPReadFilterD2Ev + 115
8     CoreFoundation                        0x2e883e2f CFRelease + 467
9     CFNetwork                             0x2e56b2a7 _ZN13NetConnectionD2Ev + 99
10   CFNetwork                              0x2e56b23f _ZN17HTTPNetConnectionD2Ev + 79
11   CFNetwork                              0x2e56b1a3 _ZN24HTTPNetConnection_NoAuthD0Ev + 11
12   CoreFoundation                         0x2e8fcab9 __CFArrayReleaseValues + 197
13   CoreFoundation                         0x2e883e2f CFRelease + 467
14   CFNetwork                              0x2e5b05af _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry20purgeIdleConnectionsEdd + 271
15   CFNetwork                              0x2e56b9d1 _ZN19HTTPConnectionCache16performIdleSweepEv + 161
16   CFNetwork                              0x2e5aea6f _ZN19HTTPConnectionCache26timeoutIdleCellConnectionsEv + 23
17   CFNetwork                              0x2e5ee337 ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 19
18   CoreFoundation                         0x2e886ea1 CFArrayApplyFunction + 37
19   CFNetwork                              0x2e554e05 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 165
20   CFNetwork                              0x2e554cd5 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 221
21   CFNetwork                              0x2e554b65 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 49
22   CoreFoundation                         0x2e91ef1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
23   CoreFoundation                         0x2e91e3e7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 207
24   CoreFoundation                         0x2e91cbd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 631
25   CoreFoundation                         0x2e887471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
26   CoreFoundation                         0x2e887253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
27   Foundation                             0x2f2c24c1 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 321
28   Foundation                             0x2f337c37 __NSThread__main__ + 1063
29   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
30   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
31   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39260440 __select + 20
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
2     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
3     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924da84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91e559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91cc79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5     Foundation                            0x2f275697 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 255
6     Foundation                            0x2f2c64d9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7     Vieu                                  0x000c9c9b +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:149)
8     Foundation                            0x2f337c37 __NSThread__main__ + 1063
9     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
10   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
11   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924dad4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1     MediaToolbox                          0x2fd76a0f fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1755
2     CoreMedia                             0x2eeb3217 figThreadMain + 195
3     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
4     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
5     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924da84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91e559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91cc79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5     libAVFAudio.dylib                     0x2d8f65b3 _ZN20GenericRunLoopThread5EntryEPv + 131
6     libAVFAudio.dylib                     0x2d8eaaff _ZN9CAPThread5EntryEPS_ + 179
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
9     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924da84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     MediaToolbox                          0x2fd7ce19 FigExpressNotificationThread + 89
2     CoreMedia                             0x2eeb3217 figThreadMain + 195
3     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
4     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
5     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39260c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cc4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924da84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91e559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91cc79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5     libAVFAudio.dylib                     0x2d8f65b3 _ZN20GenericRunLoopThread5EntryEPv + 131
6     libAVFAudio.dylib                     0x2d8eaaff _ZN9CAPThread5EntryEPS_ + 179
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
9     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x3924da84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91e559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2     CoreFoundation                        0x2e91cc79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4     CoreFoundation                        0x2e887253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5     AudioToolbox                          0x2e25e46b _ZN20GenericRunLoopThread5EntryEPv + 131
6     AudioToolbox                          0x2e244773 _ZN9CAPThread5EntryEPS_ + 211
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6bcf _pthread_start + 103
9     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39260c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cc4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39260c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cc4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39260c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cc4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39260c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c4cc4 start_wqthread + 8



Crashed Registers
_________________________________
r12 0x3b0882ec
r10 0x2f1a9ec
r11 0x394687e0
cpsr    0x20000030
r4  0x18832b90
r5  0x6c03
r6  0x1013380
r7  0x2f1a9e0
r0  0x2f1a96c
r1  0x200
r2  0x0
r3  0x200
sp  0x2f1a96c
r8  0x3929c2e9
r9  0x0
pc  0x39199758
lr  0x3929c2df
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an exception breakpoint?

Comment: Unfortunately this crash is not reproducible, I got it as a crash report on Crittercism

Comment: Looks like connection died on cellular network, but no idea why this happened and why this crashed app

Comment: It isn't full crash log. I can't see what kind of signal was sent to application. Could you review original log and update info here?

Comment: @VladimirPopko Name - SIGSEGV, Reason - SEGV_ACCERR

Comment: Seems to me like it died when a loop was detected. several threads are active in fact 4 are just starting - did the entire phone died or was it just the app?

Comment: The app died, the phone was OK at that time.

Comment: I'd look for the routine where threads are started and see if data can trigger a loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "where threads are started"? The problem is that there's no explicit origin that's related to my code here.

Comment: IT will be hard to relate this to the code without seeing your code but in one of the threads you have this: (the loop can be in a called function -  the NSThread portion after seems to be repeated in the other threads:)  Vieu                                  0x000c9c9b +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:149)
8     Foundation                            0x2f337c37 __NSThread__main__ + 1063
9     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x392c6c5d _pthread_body + 141

Comment: Thanks @Paulo I really appreciate your help. Doesn't it make sense that this is unrelated to the crash due to the fact that it's not the crashed thread? This could have been a process running on a separate thread alongside whatever it was that caused the crash.

Comment: Is this anywhere in your crash report? ``0x8badf00d`` ?

Comment: @quellish no it is not

Comment: @Paulo I see the networkRequestThreadEntryPoint anytime when I just pause execution. It's AFNetworking's thread and I don't think it's related. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Here's something that looks similar, though no solution: https://github.com/PhilipsHue/PhilipsHueSDK-iOS-OSX/issues/52

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need investigate calls of these functions: `mach_msg_trap` and `semaphore_wait_trap`. It is the main reason of crash. Sometimes calls of these methods at the top of stack are indicators of receiving deadlock. Here some links for investigation:

- [IOS semaphore_wait_trap on main thread causing hang in UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473448/ios-semaphore-wait-trap-on-main-thread-causing-hang-in-ui)
- http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7354-what-means-mach-msg-trap.html
- [Deadlock using AFIncrementalStore and NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077982/deadlock-using-afincrementalstore-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Try to reproduce crash by starting application, open url connections, send application to background, wait few seconds and then bring it to foreground.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort though this answer didn't help me find the origin of the crash.